# Xcode include header files from other sub project

Tags: xcode, include-path, subproject

I have a main Xcode project (in C++) with many subprojects.

In subproject A, I want to include some header files in subproject B where B's product could be a dynamic library.

How can I set it up so that there will be no "file not found" error or linker error?